# How to trace the access to Firefox's password manager?

Tags: firefox, password-management, tracing

Recently my Firefox started to prompt me for the password manager's master password right after starting it which is quite annoying, and I can't find what's triggering it. This change in behavior *seems* to coincide with the update to 34.0, but I'm not sure. Firebug's network monitor shows no network activity, and it also happens when all add-ons are disabled.

My question (which might be an X-Y problem....) is: Is there a way to log/trace the access to the password manager in order to find out what's triggering it? (apart from building Firefox with debug symbols and then having a happy debug session.)

Answer (score 0):

Is that maybe firefox itself asking you to "decrypt" or "identify yourself" before it will reveal all your passwords? Maybe a new feature?

My about:config has this entry

> security.ask_for_password
>
> Integer
>
> Determines when Mozilla Mail should ask for the master password.
>
> 0
>   (default): Only the first time it's needed
>
> 1: Every time it's needed
>
> 2: Every n minutes, where n is the value in
>   security.password_lifetime.

Or could be a bug or incompatibility with an addon, lots of google results including this one: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/866291#answer-257775

Here's a quote from a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox-3.0/+bug/276366) that supports the addon theory:

> When you have a master password set, Firefox asks for it when you
>   first load a tab with a login form that you've stored a password for
>   (even if the tab is in the background) or when an extension (like
>   Foxmarks) asks for a stored password.

To find that, try disabling addons one at a time & see when it stops. Or disable them all first and see *if* it stops, then enable one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same (indeed very annoying) problem with the version 34 update. The prompt (at startup) disappeared after I deactivated firefox Sync (you know, synchronization of bookmarks, etc).

My suggestion for a solution is: deactivate "Sync" (no automatic "Sign in to Sync") and only use it manually until this problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is the description on how to deal with tracing of password manager activities: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox:Password_Manager_Debugging and it really works.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.